# Can you connect more than one 3DS controller to Smash Wii U?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, wii-u, super-smash-bros-4

Is this possible? I unfortunately don't have more than one 3ds with Smash installed, so it is impossible for me to check. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, [direct quote from the Smashbros website](http://www.smashbros.com/en-uk/howto/entry11.html):

> You can play with a number of different controllers in the Wii U version.
>
> [...]
>
> ## Nintendo 3DS and 2DS systems
>
> You can use Nintendo 3DS and 2DS systems as controllers, as long as you have a copy of Super Smash Bros. for Nintendo 3DS for each system.

The mention: "for each system" implies that multiple 3DS/2DS systems can be used simultaneously.

Comment: When you quote something, don't forget to add a link to where you found the quote.

Comment: @Nolonar new to this whole stackexchange thing, will do next time

Comment: Not a problem. I also hope you don't mind my (somewhat extensive) edit. Welcome to Arqade, by the way.